# Change in Word file with PHP

Tags: php, ms-word, docx

I created a Word file (I mean `.docx`) and define some keyword (as variable) like `{FIRSTNAME}` , `{LASTNAME}` and ...

How can I change the keywords in `.docx` file with PHP ? is it possbile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try PHPWord.  Click [here](https://phpword.codeplex.com/) to check it out.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I read the documentation of PHPWord, but how can I change the my keywords in word file ?